# Integration of a rational function

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the following integral.

$$ \int \frac{x^4}{x^2-16}\ dx $$

My try :

I did the long division and I got $ \frac{x^4}{x^2-16} = x^2+16 + \frac{256}{x^2-16} $

$$ \int \frac{x^4}{x^2-16}\ dx $$
$$ \int x^2\ dx + \int 16\ dx +\ 256\int \frac{1}{x^2-16}\ dx$$
$$ \frac{x^3}{3} + 16x + 256\  ln\ |x^2-16| + C $$

But the answer in the book is

$$ \frac{x^3}{3} + 16x + 32\ \ln\ |x-4| - 32\ \ln\ |x+4| + C $$

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Please elaborate the long division. Do you assert $\frac{x^4}{x^2 - 16} = \frac{256}{x^2 - 16}$?

Comment: No Sorry that was a mistake. I edited it. $ \frac{x^4}{x^2-16} = x^2+16+ \frac{256}{x^2-16}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method is right but in integration of
  $$\int\frac{1}{x^2-16}dx=\int\frac{1}{(x-4)(x+4)}dx=\int\frac{1}{8}[\frac{1}{x-4}-\frac{1}{x+4}]dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{8}[ln(x-4)-ln(x+4)]$$
Hence $$\int\frac{x^4}{x^2-16}=\frac{x^3}{3} + 16x + 256.\frac{1}{8}[ln(x-4)-ln(x+4)]+C$$
$$=\frac{x^3}{3} + 16x +32ln(x-4)-32ln(x+4)+C$$

THANKS

Comment: How did you get from $ \int \frac{1}{(x-4)(x+4)}\ dx $ to $ \int \frac{1}{8}[\frac{1}{x-4}-\frac{1}{x+4}\] dx $ ?

Comment: Partial fractions.

Comment: That was what I stated in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try partial fractions:
$\frac{x^4}{x^2-16} = x^2 +16-\frac{32}{x+4}+\frac{32}{x-4}$.

Comment: How is  $ \frac{256}{x^2-16} = -\frac{32}{x+4}+ \frac{32}{x-4}$ ?

Comment: Just multiply the right hand side out, and notice that $x^2-16=(x+4)(x-4)$.

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't i just take the 256 outside of the integral sign and then integrate $ \frac{1}{x^2-16} $ which will equal $ ln\ |x^2-16|$ ?

Comment: One reason is that integrating ${ 1\over x^2 -16}$ will not result in $\ln |x^2-16|$.

Comment: Since $\frac{256}{x^2-16} = -\frac{32}{x+4}+ \frac{32}{x-4}$, you have $\int \frac{256}{x^2-16}dx = -32 \ln |x+4| + 32 \ln |x-4| +C$.